# For what value(s) of k, if any, will the system have no solution, a unique solution, and infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{cases}
x  −  2y  +  5z  =  2
\\
x  +  y  +  z  =  k
\\
2x  −  y  +  6z  =  k^2
\end{cases}$$

For which value(s) of k does this system of linear equations have no solutions/unique solution/infinite sol?

Using Gauss elimination I end up with this matrix, not sure how to proceed.

\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&5&2\\0&3&-4&k-2\\0&0&0&k^2-k-2\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Consider transforming this into the matrix representation, apply gaussian elimination, and draw conclusions from the rank of your matrix

Comment: Do you know about matrices? What is the title of the class you are in?

Comment: Basically follow the same approach here from a very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939030/for-what-values-of-k-will-these-equations-have-no-solution-infinite-solutions?rq=1

Comment: @RSerrao, I have not included my progress in the question because I did not know the formatting for matrices, I have now added this in. I have used Gauss elim but am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @TheCount, I do know about matrices, see question for more info. Apologies for not including this earlier.

Comment: @Boa, great! Try to row reduce again to get all the "k" terms together in the bottom right.

Comment: @Boa I believe you have made a mistake on the gaussian elimination step. Start by noticing that adding the first and second equations you get the third one. What does that imply?

Comment: Boa, no worries. We are friendly here. @tbone's suggestion is a good one. Does it make sense?

Comment: @RSerrao ok, but that doesn't change the fact that it is a good suggestion, and will still be one after the mistake is addressed, and in the future.

Comment: @RSerrao, Thanks, spotted and fixed my mistake, is it correct now?

Comment: @Boa not really. I believe you are making a mistake when eliminating the first 1 from the second row. Pay attention to the minus signs.

Comment: @RSerrao, Also, it implies that k+2 = k^2, how should I use this information?

Comment: @Boa firstly it implies that the rank of the matrix cannot be 3 and that your gauss is still wrong :( but it also means that if $k + 2 \not= k^2$ there is no solution

Comment: @RSerrao Ok I believe I have fixed it now, also found that this system has infinite solutions when k = -1 or k= 2, correct?

Comment: @Boa precisely. If $k $ is not -1 nor 2 does it have solutions?

Comment: @RSerrao I believe it does, is there any way to find out specifically which numbers it does have solutions for instead of substituting numbers? for example I tried k=1 and it does have a solution.

Comment: @Boa if k is not -1, 2 then the polynomial on the bottom is not 0 and then you have $0x + 0y + 0z = c $ where $c $ is not 0. Is that solvable?

Comment: @RSerrao Ah right it all makes sense now, been a long day and the gauss error really put me off, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Boa no problem, we all make mistakes. Just now i replied to another guy saying he was wrong and then we understood that I was the one that was actually wrong. Rest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Gauss elimination, we get:
$$
A u = b \iff \\
[ A \mid b ] = \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -2 & 5 & 2 \\
1 &  1 & 1 & k \\
2 & -1 & 6 & k^2
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -2 & 5 & 2 \\
0 &  3 & -4 & k-2 \\
0 &  3 & -4 & k^2-4
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -2 &  5 & 2 \\
0 &  3 & -4 & k-2 \\
0 &  0 &  0 & k^2-k-2
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -2 &  5 & 2 \\
0 &  1 & -4/3 & (k-2)/3 \\
0 &  0 &  0 & k^2-k-2
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The last row determines, if there are solutions or not.
To be consistent, we must have $k$ such that
$$
k^2 - k - 2 = 0
$$
otherwise there will be no solutions to the system, as this last equation can not be fulfilled.
We have
$$
0 = k^2 - k - 2 = (k - 1/2)^2 - 1/4 - 2 = (k - 1/2)^2 - 9/4 \iff \\
k = (1/2) \pm (3/2) \in \{ -1, 2 \} 
$$
Case $k = -1$:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -2 &    5 & 2 \\
0 &  1 & -4/3 & -1 \\
0 &  0 &    0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 &  7/3 &  0 \\
0 & 1 & -4/3 & -1 \\
0 & 0 &    0 &  0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
This gives the infinite many solutions $((-7/3)z, -1 + (4/3) z, z)$ where $z$ is an arbitrary real number.

Case $k = 2$:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -2 &    5 & 2 \\
0 &  1 & -4/3 & 0 \\
0 &  0 &    0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 &  7/3 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & -4/3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &    0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
This gives the infinite many solutions
$(2-(7/3)z, (4/3)z, z)$
where $z$ is an arbitrary real number.

**Summary:**

- no solutions if $k \not\in \{ -1, 2 \}$
- unique solutions will not happen
- infinite many solutions for $k \in \{ -1, 2 \}$